# How can I read files in my WEB-INF directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-inf

I'm running Java web application using Tomcat and I want to read a `Properties` file that's located in my `WEB-INF` directory.  How can I get an `InputStream` to this `Properties` file so I can read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServletContext.getResource`/`getResourceAsStream`, IIRC.

Comment: I want to know the path on the server's file-system to the resource - can you tell me how to find this out?

Comment: @TimCooper The servlet spec doesn't support this. This is because the file might not directly exist on the filesystem — it might be served directly from a .war file. What are you trying to do?